# Connect multiple (3+) iPads/iPhones over bluetooth ad-hoc network?

Tags: iphone, ipad, networking, bluetooth

I'm curious if it's possible to have more than two iPads/iPhones connected to one another over a bluetooth network simultaneously. I'd like to design a network game that supports more than two players but I can't find any information to determine if this is even possible.

Comment: Does BT even support an ad-hoc configuration like that? What about WiFi instead?

Comment: Wasn't sure. I've hardly used bluetooth at all. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth only supports Device-to-Device not AdHoc. As "pst" suggests, WiFi is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

if... you want to try.... first they would have to be jailbroken.
on cydia, try out the wywi app >> bluetooth tether with the pc

it has other functions like usb tethering, its the best tethering app if you dont care about revealing your connection to your carrier, but that doesnt suit the case

i know for a fact that you can tether as ad hoc via usb tethering, i believe the bt tethering should work the same